# Not update foreign key fields in templates django

Tags: django

I have a models related by ForeignKey and Form for my code, I try to display in one page:
All Quotes and their items, also i want to update this fields.

**Model**

```
class Quote(models.Model):
    number = models.IntegerField(null=False)

class Quote_detail(models.Model):
    quote = models.ForeignKey(Quote)
    stock = models.IntegerField(null=True)
```

**Form**

```
class QuoteForm(forms.ModelForm):

class Meta:
    model = Quote
    fields = '__all__'
```

**View**

```
def quotes(request):
    cotiFormSet = modelformset_factory(Quote,form=QuoteForm)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        formSet = QuoteForm(request.POST,request.FILES)
        if formSet.is_valid():
            formSet.save()
            return redirect('quotes')
    else:
        formSet = cotiFormSet()
    return render(request,'supplierweb/quotes.html', {'formset':formSet})
```

and

**Template**

```
{% for item in form.instance.quote_detail_set.all %}
<tr>
    <td>
        <input for={{ item.stock }} value = {{ item.stock }} type="number" />
    </td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

But, when i submit this page, fields not update. Thanks for your help!

Comment: The HTML in your template looks quite malformed. `for` is not a valid attribute on an input field. It also has no `name` attribute so nothing will actually get POSTed. You should consider letting Django [render the form fields for you](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/forms/formsets/#using-a-formset-in-views-and-templates).

Answer (score 0):

**forms.py**

```
class QuoteForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Quote_detail # Not Quote!
        fields = ['stock'] # Or exclude = [] if you need all fields
```

**template.html**

```
...
{% for form in formset %}
    {% form.as_table %}
{% endfor %}
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I can recomment the django Girls Tutorial to implement your forms, cause django can do most of the work for you.

http://tutorial.djangogirls.org/en/django_forms/

Your template.html would look like this. You only need to change the from used in this template to yours.

```
{% block content %}
    <form method="POST" class="post-form">{% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <button type="submit" class="save btn btn-default">Save</button>
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```